# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Me podrían apoyar por favor. Estoy realizando un código en python flask.
A través de postman quiero cargar un archivo .docx y este convertirlo en base64, estoy haciendo lo siguiente pero me da el error del titulo.

```
from io import TextIOWrapper
import base64

@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def base64image():
try:
    uploaded_file = TextIOWrapper(request.files['file'])
    print(uploaded_file)

    data = open(uploaded_file, "w")
    encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
    print(data)
    print(encoded)
except Exception as ex:
    print("MISTAKE: " + str(ex))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que convertirlo a TextIOWrapper está de más

podría quedar solo como

```
try:
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    print(uploaded_file)

    encoded = base64.b64encode(uploaded_file.read())
    print(data)
    print(encoded)
except Exception as ex:
    print("MISTAKE: " + str(ex))
```